# Simultaneous extracellular recording from different distant sites (in rodents)

Tags: neuroscience, electrophysiology, experimental-neuroscience

I wonder whether it is technically possible today to have simultaneous extracellular recording in awake rodents (e.g., mice) from different non-proximate sites (e.g., V1 and frontal cortex). I mean to have two or more different electrode penetrations at the same time. Using multi-array / grid / tetrode  it is possible record from many locations, but they are spatially proximate. Any references are appreciated.

Comment: This is very widely done!!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't know why multi-site cortical extracellular recordings would not be feasible? What would the practical experimental or technical limitation be in your opinion?

As long as you have a [multichannel amplifier suitable for extracellular recording](http://alascience.com/product/extracellular-multichannel/) and you consider the choice between using a common reference, *i.e.*, monopolar recordings [(Ludwig *et al*., 2009)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2666412/), or using paired recording-reference electrodes for bipolar measurements [(Boatman-Reich *et al*., 2010)](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fncom.2010.00004/full) you should be fine.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Boatman-Reich *et al*., *Front Comput Neurosci* (2010)](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fncom.2010.00004/full)

**-** [Ludwig *et al*., *J Neurophysiol* (2009); **101**(3): 1679–89](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2666412/)</sub>